# C++ Delete a pointer using delete []?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Here is the sample code piece in C++:

```
Foo *ptr;
ptr = new Foo;
delete [] ptr;
```

Could this run into problem? What should be the correct way to delete such a pointer and free the memory?

Thank you

Comment: delete if it's single object and delete [] if you want to delete array.

Comment: Are you really asking for the correct way to use `new` and `delete` because you haven't been able to find *any* information anywhere else? Please put a little effort into learning the language yourself before posting questions.

Comment: match all `delete`s with `new`s and all `delete []`s with `new xyz []`s

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, that could run into a problem. Or not. Technically what it does is *undefined*.

Every `new` must have exactly one `delete`; every `new[]` must have exactly one `delete[]`.

In your particular instance a correct code path might be:

```
Foo *ptr;
ptr = new Foo;
delete ptr;
```

or

```
Foo *ptr;
ptr = new Foo[7];
delete[] ptr;
```

Comment: But of course, there's never really any case where you'd use `new Foo[7]`, so there's never any case for `delete[]`.

Answer (score 5):

You should delete it without `[]`. Just simple `delete`:

```
Foo *ptr;
ptr = new Foo;
delete ptr;
```

Answer (score 3):

`delete[]` is used for deleting an *array* of dynamic allocated objects, which is not your case. Here, using `delete ptr;` is fine.

- when a single element is allocated, like `int *pointer = new int`

  `delete pointer;`
- when an array of elements is allocated, like `int *pointer = new int[5]`

  `delete [] pointer;`

Answer (score 2):

Quite likely to cause problems, because `delete []` needs to store the number of elements in the array, so that it knows how many times to call destructors. Since `new Foo` doesn't have to store that information (as it's not required for `delete`), it's entirely possible that `delete []` will use "rubbish" as input.